# Post and get html data in laravel and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, http-post

I want to post some HTML content to a route and show the processed HTML result in a new window. I have created a button for preview HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="preview" onclick="tempopen();" />
</div>
```

in `tempopen` function I have created an ajax function for sending data to a route for showing preview HTML

```
url = "<?php echo(URL::to('page_temp'))?>";
var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
var leader = document.getElementById("leader").value;
var content = document.getElementById("editor1").value;
var image_show = document.getElementById("image_show").value;
var imagelink = document.getElementById("image").src;
var image = imagelink.substring(imagelink.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {title: title},
            success: function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

and at last in `page_temp` route a simple function is written for testing receiving data and sending a feedback, but I have got this error
POST XHR http://localhost/page_temp

Answer (score 0):

What is the url you call? It's "". Should be a real url. So var url = "/" or try to use the complete http route